# Google Cloud Speech to Text in Electron: "error reading first path in the walk C:\...\protos"

Tags: webpack, error-handling, google-cloud-platform, electron, speech-to-text

I generated a Vue app via the Vue CLI 3, and then added the `electron-builder` plugin (`vue add electron-builder`).
Then, I attempted to run:

```
yarn add @google-cloud/speech
```

Afterwards, from the `background.js`, just to ensure that I can load the desktop app, I added on top of the file:

```js
import speech from "@google-cloud/speech";
```

When I'm starting the application (`yarn electron:serve`), I'm getting:

```
Error: error reading first path in the walk C:\Repositories\protos
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Repositories\protos'
```

When I first Googled this error, I arrived at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885985/google-cloud-tts-import-error-error-reading-first-path-in-the-walk-c-users#comment100619961_56885985).
After reading the [article](https://codeburst.io/use-webpack-with-dirname-correctly-4cad3b265a92) that this answer is linking to, I created `<root>\webpack.config.js` and put in it:

```js
import path from "path";

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "background.js"),
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  }
};
```

It didn't help. I'm still getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: I solved it by setting `__dirname` to `true`. Did you try that?